# Find Index from List

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Dictionary that contains thread Information `Dictionary<String,Thread>`

```
"2FF"
"2IE"
"7CH"
```

etc

what i know is integers 2,7 etc what i want to know that in Dictionary how many strings contain the given integer if it is there then get that string

Eg

```
String GetString(int integer)
{
//if Dictionary contains given intgr return whole string in which that integer is present
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the multi-threading aspect here? And is it a list or a dictionary?

Comment: the question is not really clear ...

Comment: And more importantly, what is an Intiger? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LINQ syntax:

```
var matchingThreads = from pair in dictionary
                   where pair.Key.StartsWith(number.ToString())
                   select pair.Value;
```

With traditional syntax:

```
var matchingThreads = dictionary
                .Where(pair => pair.Key.StartsWith(number.ToString()))
                .Select(pair => pair.Value);
```

If you only need to **count** them and you don't care about the `Thread` objects, you can use:

```
int count = dictionary.Keys.Count(key => key.StartsWith(number.ToString()))
```

Note that you need a `using System.Linq` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a List<CustomClass> would be a better choice here where CustomClass would look like:

```
public sealed class CustomClass
{
   public Thread Thread { get; set; }
   public string String { get; set; }
}
```

(Better property names are alway good, of course :-) )

A dictionary is not sutitable if you do  not know the exact keys or only parts of them.

You could then use LINQ to find out what you want, e.g.:

```
int count = list.Where(c => c.String.StartsWith(integer.ToString())).Count();
//or
IEnumerable<string> strings = list.Where(c => c.String.StartsWith(integer.ToString())).Select(c => c.String);
```

Comment: Linq can be used with Dictionaries as well.

Comment: Yeah - but why using a dictionary if you don't use its features?

Comment: What makes you think he's not using the other features? As far as I understand, the key is a string and the value is a thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMatchingKeys(int value)
{
    var valueText = value.ToString();

    return _dictionary.Keys.Where(key => key.Contains(valueText));
}
```

Comment: Note that this will return the matching strings themselves.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: Thanks, I made it work that way based on the OP's requirements of "if it is there then get that string" and "if Dictionary contains given intgr return whole string in which that intgr is present".